# MySql and SQL Server resources utilization comparision

Tags: mysql, sql-server, apache, iis

Does Apache with MySql will use less system resources (RAM, CPU utilization) if we develop a web application instead of IIS with Sql Server?

My friend told that MYSQL consume very less when compared to SQL Server.

I have both PHP and ASP.NET skills. Which one will be preferable to develop application?

Answer (score 0):

This will more depend on what you're doing. My experience is that ASP.NET runs circles around PHP when it comes to speed - though most of the times it doesn't matter as you're spending most time doing IO or waiting for the DB:

As for resources consumed, MySQL by default uses very little, if you really want more speed you'll have to tune it - which among other things means tune it to use more resources - RAM in particular. SQL Server is a more complex and feature rich database compared to MySQL - and by default it'll use more resources compared to MySQL, which you can tune down if you so wish.